# Best practice to avoid code replication?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-view

currently I have to change a view, a big part of the view code looks like this:

```
CAST('My_Tag_' + CASE 
        WHEN FieldX isnull
            THEN ''
        WHEN FieldX = '123'
            THEN 'some_number'
        WHEN FieldX = 'abc'
            THEN 'some_text'
        ELSE 'strange' ) AS VARCHAR(128) AS myField
)
```

Just a chunk of code, that puts together a string (the code itself doesn't even matter right now, I have like 50 other examples, where I have a lot of code replication). Now I have exact the same code for 30 more fields in the view, just the 'My_Tag_' and FieldX is changing. If this would be C#, I would just write a little helper function.
Of course I could write a function here, too. But as this is a bigger project with a lot of tables, views, etc, I would have hundreds of functions soon.

Now I am pretty new to SQL and normally my home is the OOP-world. But there has to be a solution to avoid code replication and to avoid having hundreds of helper functions in the database?

What's best practice in this case?

Comment: try using Scalar Value Functions.. and put the code in it to return the VARCHAR(128)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice may be to create a [user defined function](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions).

The arguments would be the fields that change and it would return the intended value.

Comment: But if every developer would add his little helper functions to the database, we would easily hit 1000 functions within half a year. Still the best way?

Comment: What I understand is that the helper function would be similar, only the `'My_Tag_'` and `FieldX` is changing. So you can put those as input parameters of the function.

Comment: Yes, for this case. But there are like 50 other, totally different views on this database, where you would need like 5 different helper functions for each view to avoid code duplication. We would have cleaner code, but we would have hundreds of helper-functions.

Comment: Like you said, cleaner code. That might be the best way to proceed here.

Comment: Ok, then I will go with functions for now... I will ask in a few months again, how to handle 500 functions. :D

Comment: Don't forget that you can have another input parameter to define which select to make :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to add a field to a table:

```
; with  TableWithExtraField as
        (
        select  case ... end as NewField
        ,       table1
        )
select   NewField
from     TableWithExtraField
```

Or a subquery also works:

```
select  NewField
from    (
        select  case ... end as NewField
        ,       table1
        ) as TableWithExtraField
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyTag(@myfield VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST('My_Tag_' + CASE 
        WHEN @myfield IS NULL 
            THEN ''
        WHEN @myfield = '123'
            THEN 'some_number'
        WHEN @myfield = 'abc'
            THEN 'some_text'
        ELSE 'strange' END AS VARCHAR(128)) 
)
END
```